# Is there anyway to avoid processing same file twice with Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am working on the 3 steps Spring Batch project. Firstly, it downloads needed text files from ftp to local, then process it, and finally delete files in the local directory every 10 minutes. And every 10 minutes there are new files loaded in the FTP. What if there emerge some problem in the FTP and it does not load new files? Then Spring Batch project download same file and process it again. So my question is that how can avoid Spring Batch to process same file twice?

Edit: I have used Apache common library to download files from FTP.
And I am using MultiResourceItemReader to pull 2 text files at each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the file name as a job parameter. This will create a job instance for each file.

Now since Spring Batch prevents running the same job instance to completion more than once, then each file would be processed only once and you could avoid processing the same file twice by design.

Comment: Can you provide any example? How can I use the file name as a job parameter if I get the file name in step1(Dowloading file from ftp) tasklet?

Comment: Well, if you know which file to download in step 1, you can pass its name as a parameter to the job and get it in step 1.

Comment: may I use execution context for this purpose?

Comment: No need for the execution context, you can get the job parameter in the tasklet of step1 thanks to the provided chunkContext: `chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters()`.

Comment: Man, thank you for all. But actually I am new in Spring Batch. And therefore I have no imagination about this part of Spring Batch. Then how I can pass parameter in step1? If available, Can you share any resource code something like that to look at and get to understand?

Comment: You are welcome. No worries, always happy to help. If you edit the question and share your code, I will edit the answer and show you how to pass the file name as a job parameter and get it in the step.

Comment: I have searched on the net and got that to add this into the tasklet chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("inputFile", inputFilename); would put parameter? What do u think? would it help me alone?

Comment: I couldn't share because of privacy. This is not my project.

Comment: Man, I did not know the file name beforehand, I get the file name in step1 and download it just after know its name.

Comment: That's another story, so you can't use the trick of passing the file name as a job parameter.. What you can do is store the name of each processed file in a persistent store, and do a check in step1 if the current file has been processed or not before proceeding.