# Is it possible to put JobParameter in Tasklet step? (Spring Batch)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I need to avoid process same file twice in Spring Batch project. Therefore I need to put file name as a Job Parameter. However, I know file name only in step1, not before the job execution. Therefore I can't pass file name as a job parameter while launching a job. My question is that, is there any other way to pass job parameter in step1 after get to know file name?

Comment: If you don't know the file name upfront, then you can't use it as a job parameter to benefit from the design of Spring Batch that prevents a successful job instance to run twice as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61385731/5019386. So the answer by Julien is correct. In your case, you can store the name of each processed file in a persistent store and check if the current file has been already processed or not before proceeding. If the file name is not enough, a common technique is to checksum the file (md5, sha1, etc) and see if the content is the same as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a parameter to Spring Batch, you need to pass data between steps. Here are some ways to do that => [Storing in JobExecutionContext from tasklet and accessing in another tasklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117060/storing-in-jobexecutioncontext-from-tasklet-and-accessing-in-another-tasklet)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Man, Thank you for your answer but how I can avoid processing same file twice with passing data between steps?

Comment: Post some code showing your Job Configuration to get some help